# how to stop buffering(blinking ) in my applet

Tags: java, graphics, japplet

I am making a card game with a java applet. I have a class that extends JApplet. Now I am trying to draw 104 images on applet, but when I drag one image and move, my entire applet is blinking. Throughout the execution of my program, I am calling the repaint method in mousedragged and mousepressed, because it is required to repaint the image on the applet after dragging it.

I know my paint method is running every time I drag a card and move the mouse across the screen, and that's why my 104 cards redraw on applet every time. I think this is the reason for blinking in my applet.

I have tried many times but not solving.  How can I prevent this blinking?

Answer (score 5):

Look into double buffering and [BufferStrategy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html).

Once upon a time you'd do it yourself by painting to an offscreen image then drawing the offscreen image to your applet in a single go - but these days you can use BufferStrategy. Here's a [tutorial on how to do it the old fashioned way](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/DoubleBuffering.html).  BufferStrategy javadoc shows you how to use the new way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have used  BufferStrategy, now 70% solved my problem. Thanks alot